# OBS Studio multitrack audio exports only one track

Tags: audio-recording, obs

I have OBS Studio configured to combine different audio inputs into several audio tracks/channels using its built-in mixer. But when OBS saves a local copy of the stream, the video file only has one audio track, not the several I configured. I'm exporting the video to MKV file, as I thought it would be the most versatile format and had support for multiple audio/video tracks.

Is this a configuration issue or is there something else to keep in mind? Perhaps a different export file format would be better? I'd still like to retain all (multiple) audio tracks within the single exported file.

Answer (score 1):

In OBS Studio go to Settigns->Output->Recording and under Recording Format you have Audio Track. You have to enable audio tracks that you set up in audio mixer. You can also name them in Audio tab.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what operating system you're using, but I know that personally, myself, using Mac OS, I have had great luck with similar issue either fiddling around with the Audio MIDI configuration app in the /Applications/Utilities folder.  But, better than that, there's an awesome application called "CaptureSync"(http://www.bensoftware.com - there's a free version floating around) -- and it's got the nice feature to be able to not only be configured for up to 4 different audio inputs/video inputs (including, for example, having one of the 4 choices being your actual total output style from OBS studio, to act somewhat like a "mix-minus" setup for lack of a better term to use), and this way you can utilize the mixer within OBS, and then use this app (or another one like it, if this helps you) to then get a separated group of files, each with their own audio tracks and video tracks.  So you can set them up with one of the 4 inputs being linked to a USB webcam, or an internal/external monitor display, a video file, etc.

It's quite useful, hope that helps.